# Error while compiling octave standalone programs through visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, octave

I have downloaded and installed Octave for windows from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/octave/windows/octave-4.0.3-installer.exe . I am trying to run one of the standalone program provided by Octave through visual studio 2013. Below is the program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>

int
main (void)
{
  std::cout << "Hello Octave world!\n";

  int n = 2;
  Matrix a_matrix = Matrix (n, n);

  for (octave_idx_type i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (octave_idx_type j = 0; j < n; j++)
      a_matrix(i,j) = (i + 1) * 10 + (j + 1);

  std::cout << a_matrix;

  return 0;
}
```

While compiling I am getting below errors

```
Error   1   error C2065: '__asm__' : undeclared identifier  C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.3\include\math.h   169 1   Test
Error   2   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '__volatile__'    C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.3\include\math.h   169 1   Test
Error   3   error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before ':'  C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.3\include\math.h   169 1   Test
Error   4   error C2059: syntax error : ')' C:\Octave\Octave-4.0.3\include\math.h   169 1   Test
```

I have properly included octave header files in project properties but still I am getting these errors. Could someone help me out here?

Comment: the error lies elsewhere, probably in `octave/oct.h` or dependencies. It defines its own `math.h`, which is a first possible conflict.

Comment: yes but I am not sure from where its originated.

Comment: in Visual studio `__asm__` should be `__asm` (without the trailing underscores). Could that be the issue?